# Adding values to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

The code below:

```
rect_pos = {}

rect_pos_single = [[0,0], [50, 0], [50, 100], [0, 100]]

i = 0

while (i<3): 

    for j in range(4):

        rect_pos_single[j][0] += 50

    print rect_pos_single

    rect_pos[i] = rect_pos_single

    i += 1

print rect_pos
```

The code prints subsequent iterations of the variable "rect_pos_single". Next, I add them to dictionary "rect_pos". Keys change, but value is always the same - last iteration. I do not understand why?

Comment: Have you tried extracting the element from the dictionary, performing the addition, and then re-adding it to the dictionary?

What is your expected output?  And what is your current output?

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
rect_pos_single[j][0] += 50
```

modifies the list in-place; that is, `rect_pos_single` always refers to the same list object, but you change the contents of that list.

This line

```
rect_pos[i] = rect_pos_single
```

assigns a reference to the list referenced by `rect_pos_single` to `rect_pos[i]`. Each element of `rect_pos` refers to the same list.

The simplest change is to assign a *copy* of the list to the dictionary with

```
rect_pos[i] = copy.deepcopy(rect_pos_single)  # Make sure you import the copy module
```

A deep copy is needed because `rect_pos_single` is a list of lists, and doing a shallow copy with `rect_pos_single` would simply create a new list with references to the same lists that are actually modified with `rect_pos_single[j][0] += 50`.